# C++ Make a class's member variable a specialization in a subclass

Tags: c++

I have 4 classes,

Class A(abstract),

Class B (abstract), (Has as a member variable, of type vector(Class A))

Class C, a subclass of class A

Class D, a subclass of class B

Can I redefine the member variable of class D to be of type vector(Class C) instead of vector(class A). Would it be better to be an array instead.

Comment: since C is derived from A you do not need to change the vector anyway. You will just need to "downcast" to C before using it.

Comment: what is the porpuse of your choice? by the way if *C subclass A*, *C* is already an *A*.a C object contains every member nad method of A plus his member and method..

Answer (score 0):

No you are not allowed to do that. It doesn't work because of the following situation:

If a function in class B adds an element to the vector that is of class A (but not Class C) this is allowed in the base class, but not for the specific subclass (C) because the type has changed.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I redefine the member variable of class D to be of type vector(Class C) instead of vector(class A).

No, you can't. Once a data member is declared in a base class, it is inherited by all derived classes in exactly the same form.

What you can do is turn the base class member into a *pointer* to `A`, and initialize to point either to an instance of `A`, or an instance of `C`.

Comment: I guess, it's already a pointer or reference, since you can't have an instance of abstract class.

Comment: So could I have a vector of pointers to class A, all pointing to class C?